# Change the negative exponentials to the positive exponentials of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

$1)$ For the polynomial

```
p = x^(-4) - x^(-3) - 2x^(-2) + 2 + 3x + x^2 + 2x^4
```

How to change the negative exponentials into the positive exponentials,

```
p = x^4 - x^3 - 2x^2 + 2 + 3x + x^2 + 2x^4
```

$2)$ Given a series of numbers with the form `(coefficient, exponent)`. Take `{2,1},{-1,2},{1,0}` and `{2,4}` for example, how to change them into a  polynomial like

```
2x - x^2 + 1 + 2x^4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit to put these in Mathematica InputForm.

Comment: `p /. x^q_ -> x^Abs[q]` ?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Than you for your edit.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = x^(-4) - x^(-3) - 2 x^(-2) + 2 + 3 x + x^2 + 2 x^4 ;
lst = {{2, 1}, {-1, 2}, {1, 0}, {2, 4}};
```

### (1)

```
Block[{Power}, Power[a_, x_?Negative] := Power[a, -x]; p]
```

> 2 + 3 x - x^2 - x^3 + 3 x^4

### (2)

```
Dot[#, x^#2]& @@ Transpose[lst]
```

> 1 + 2 x - x^2 + 2 x^4

### (3)

> *how to separate the terms with positive exponent from those with negative exponent?*

```
Pick[p, MatchQ[Optional[_] #] /@ List @@ p] & /@ {x | x^_?Positive, x^_?Negative}
```

> {3 x + x^2 + 2 x^4, 1/x^4 - 1/x^3 - 2/x^2}

Comment: Thank you. It takes time to digest the third answer.

Comment: @Leonard, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question (as modified by your comment below) you could use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series):

```
p = x^(-4)-x^(-3)-2x^(-2)+2+3x+x^2+2x^4;

Series[p, {x, Infinity, -1}] //Normal
Series[p, {x, 0, -1}] //Normal
```

> 3 x + x^2 + 2 x^4
>
> 1/x^4 - 1/x^3 - 2/x^2

For the second question, you can use [`FromCoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromCoefficientRules):

```
topoly[l_] := FromCoefficientRules[
    Replace[l, {c_, e_} :> {e} -> c, {1}],
    x
]
```

And, your example:

```
topoly[{{2,1},{-1,2},{1,0},{2,4}}]
```

> 1 + 2 x - x^2 + 2 x^4

Comment: Thank you for your help on the second question. Can I ask one more question on the first one? how to seperate the positive terms from the negative ones? That will result in $$pplus=3x + x^2 + 2x^4$$ and $$pminus=x^{-4} - x^{-3} - 2x^{-2}$$.

Answer (score 2):

```
(* Your input *)

p = x^(-4) - x^(-3) - 2 x^(-2) + 2 + 3 x + x^2 + 2 x^4;
ls = {{2, 1}, {-1, 2}, {1, 0}, {2, 4}};

(* My solutions *)

p /. x^n_?Negative :> x^(-n)

#*x^#2 & @@@ ls // Tr
```

> ```
> 2 + 3 x - x^2 - x^3 + 3 x^4
>
> 1 + 2 x - x^2 + 2 x^4
> ```

Comment: I don't like the `ReplaceAll` approach because it gives an incorrect answer for something like `(1-x)(1+1/x)`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @CarlWoll Valid point.  I should be more careful with that.